# Track traffic that lands on a unique URL (without refer or UTM info) in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

A site I manage is getting a lot of referral traffic from a 3rd party site. The 3rd party site is linking to our site like this: `example.com/page#123abc`. The 3rd party site is using `noreferrer` with the link and they won't add a UTM parameter to the link.

Accordingly the traffic from this 3rd party site is showing up in Google Analytics as Direct traffic and is hard to track.

The `#123abc` part of the URL is unique to this 3rd party site is constant, ie. it doesn't change.

Is there a way in Google Analytics I can track, tag or filter any incoming traffic that lands on page `example.com/page#123abc` so that I can better review it in the same I way I would be able to review it if it was showing the referrer info or had a UTM parameter appended?

We are using Google Analytics Universal tracking.

Comment: Are you using Google Analytics Universal or GA4?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Google Analytics Universal

Answer (score 1):

Go to Google Analytics and select Reports.
Select new custom report and select Flat table.
Add filter "Landing Page" and enter the unique part of the url.
Save the report and choose the date to show the required result.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this some more one thing that could be done would be to write a 301 redirect from `example.com/page#123abc` to `example.com/page#123abc?utm_source=tracking`.

But it feels a bit of clunky way to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per Google documentation, you can override the UTM parameters in GA4. (I understand you'll need to migrate your setup first, since you said you are still on Universal Analytics):

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11259997?hl=en

An example code would be:

```
gtag('set', {
    'campaign_id': 'google_1234',
    'campaign_name': 'Summer_fun',
    'campaign_source': 'google',
    'campaign_medium': 'cpc',
    'campaign_term': 'summer+travel',
    'campaign_content': 'logolink',
});
```